# A Proposed Converse to A Theorem on Products of Limits

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences, indeterminate-forms

Suppose $(x_n)$ is bounded and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} y_n = 0. $ It is well known that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(x_ny_n) = 0.$ My question is the following: if for all sequences $(y_n)$ for which $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} y_n = 0$ we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(x_ny_n) = 0,$ is $(x_n)$ necessarily bounded?

Comment: Do you really intend to require the statement to hold for all $(y_n)_n$ converging to $0$ simultaneously, or for each such sequence?  Perhaps more directly: what order of quantifiers did you intend?

Comment: Yes, that was quite deliberately for every sequence $(y_n)$ simultaneously. The counterexample you posted would work otherwise. Sorry if this was unclear.

Comment: After looking at your other questions, you are too advanced to not be able to do this on your own, or to at least show an attempt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is not bounded. We construct a sequence $(y_n)$ that converges to $0$ but for which $(x_ny_n)$ does not converge to $0$.

Since $(x_n)$ is not bounded, given any $N\gt 0$ and $m\gt 0$, there exists $n\gt m$ such that $|x_n|\gt N$ (there must be infinitely many terms with absolute value greater than $N$).

So, first, let $n_1$ be such that $|x_{n_1}|\gt 1$. Let $n_2\gt n_1$ be such that $|x_{n_2}|\gt 2$. Assuming $n_k$ has been defined such that $|x_{n_k}|\gt k$, let $n_{k+1}\gt n_k$ be such that $|x_{n_{k+1}}|\gt k+1$.

Now define $y_n$ to be $0$ if $n\notin \{n_k\mid k=1,2,3\ldots\}$, and $y_{n_k}=\frac{1}{x_{n_k}}$.

Note that since $|x_{n_k}|\to\infty$, then $y_n\to 0$. However, the sequence $(x_ny_n)$ consists of $0$ in all indices different from the $n_k$, and $1$s in the $n_k$ terms; this sequence either does not converge at all, let alone to $0$, or converges to $1$ (as it has a subsequence that is constant $1$).

Comment: The sequence at the end might converge to $1$, but certainly not to $0$.

Comment: @CarstenS: I guess it could, if I just get lucky enough and get a tail of the $x$s.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Suppose $(x_n)_n$ is an unbounded sequence.  Let $s_n = \max(1,\max_{i \in [1,n]} |x_n|)$.  Then $y_n = 1/s_n$ gives a $(y_n)_n$ where $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}y_n = 0$, so is in the set of sequences converging to zero.  For this $(y_n)_n$, $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} |x_n y_n| = 1$, so $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n y_n$, if it exists, is not $0$.  By contraposition, we must have that $(x_n)_n$ is a bounded sequence.

Comment: This is a proof by *contrapositive*, not by contradiction. P.S. You could have edited your deleted answer and then undeleted.

Comment: You are right.  (Again.)  Apparently, it's later here than I realize.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin : Thanks.  Fixed.

Comment: @DavidK : Apparently, I should just back away from the keyboard before I hurt myself further.   :-)  Fixing...

Comment: Looks fine to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's <s>an alternative to</s> a rephrasing of Arturo's proof.

Suppose $(x_n)$ is not bounded. [Then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523985/prove-that-every-unbounded-sequence-contains-a-monotone-subsequence-that-diverge) $(x_n)$ contains a monotone subsequence $(x_{n_i})$ diverging to $\pm\infty$. Let $y_n={1\over x_n}$ when $n=n_i$ for some $i$, and $y_n=0$ otherwise. Then $(y_n)$ converges to zero (you can fill in the details), but $(x_ny_n)$ does not converge to $0$ because it has a subsequence $(x_{n_i}y_{n_i})$ where each term equals 1.

Comment: Do we not need to add something saying only finitely many 0's occur in $(x_n)$? Otherwise you can't always define $(y_n)$ or replace terms without affecting the limit.

Comment: @KLC: Huh? First, it is not necessarily true that only finitely many terms of $x_n$ are zero; the sequence that is $n$ when $n$ is even and $0$ when $n$ is odd is not bounded. The only detail needed is to request that the subsequence not be $0$.

Comment: You should also require the subsequence to be bounded away form $0$, lest you have a bunch of $0$s at the beginning.

Comment: I would call this a rephrasing of Arturo's proof instead of an alternative to it. But I suppose with just a 15 minute gap in posting time that you didn't want to abandon the work you had already done just because he beat you to it.