# Why limsup of subsequence unbounded above doesn't have infinity as its limit?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, limsup-and-liminf

Is this statement True or False? This question is within subseqence and $\limsup$.

$$\bf\text{If $(s_n)$ is unbounded above, then $(s_n)$ contains a subsequence that has $+ \infty$ as a limit.}$$

I say true. Because if $(s_n)$ is unbounded above, then the limit is $+ \infty$. So, at least one subsequence goes to $+ \infty$.

But the solution key says: "False. Let $(s_n) = (1, 0, 1, 0, 1,...)$. Then $\limsup s_n = 1$, but for $\epsilon = 1/2 $ there are infinitely many terms smaller than 1 - 1/2."

I don't understand the solution. I saw a similar [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523985/prove-that-every-unbounded-sequence-contains-a-monotone-subsequence-that-diverge), which says it is True. Is the solution wrong?

Comment: $(s_n) = (1, 0, 1, 0, 1,...)$ is not unbounded above.

Comment: That's what I thought, so the solution key is wrong then?

Comment: Well, it looks like the answer to a different question. – Note also that your argument *“if $(s_n)$ is unbounded above, then the limit is $+ \infty$”* is wrong.

Comment: Ok, I'll double check. The solution is wrong. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you meant to say, "If $s_n$ is unbounded above, then the $\color{red}{\limsup}$ is $\infty$."